# CarrierWave: without column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, carrierwave

it's possible to CarrierWave not use column? I want to create Avatar Uploader but I don't want to save path to image in column.

Thanks.

Comment: But I don't want save path to column. I only want sent image to server.

Comment: attr_accessors aren't persisted

Comment: I don't understand you. I don't want interfere with database. I only want to upload image to server.

Comment: That's what my answer is all about: instead of creating a column, create an attr_accessor with the same name

Comment: It's not working. I get this error: "uninitialized constant Member::AvatarUploader"

Comment: Any suggestions? I got error "undefined method `avatar_will_change!' for". That my I don't have avatar column. Can I bypass this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
my_file = File.open ('./my_file.png')
uploader = AvatarUploader.new
uploader.store!(my_file)                              # size: 1024x768

uploader.url # => '/url/to/my_file.png'               # size: 800x600
uploader.thumb.url # => '/url/to/thumb_my_file.png'   # size: 200x200
```